# Output an ole object to jpg file

Tags: ms-access, vba, jpeg, data-conversion

I have a ms access database with an ole object field where I have pasted in images collected from various places from the internet, no files created before copying them into the field

the database has got rather large and I want to export the images to a file and link them rather than embed them

I have got this far

```
    Public Function exportlink()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim mstream As ADODB.Stream
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim image As Control
    Dim FN As String
    Set image = Forms!frmuseful!image
    strFullPath = "C:\Documents\pics\"
    FN = Forms!frmuseful!ID & "a" & ".jpg"
    'Create a Stream Object to contain the Binary Data from the OLE Object Field,
    '(adTypeBinary), then Open it
    Set mstream = New ADODB.Stream
    mstream.Type = adTypeBinary
    mstream.Open

    'Write the contents of the OLE Object Field to the Stream
    mstream.Write image.Value

    mstream.SaveToFile strFullPath & FN, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    End Function
```

which outputs a file but when I try to open it it says not a valid JPG file. size wise it looks more like what I could expect for a bitmap file, but changing to .bmp also gives not a valid BMP file.

I am guess that somewhere along the line I need to convert the stream to jpg format, but I am not sure how to do that

Comment: You may need to write a [BMP file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) before the image data to get a valid BMP file. Once you have that, converting to JPG is trivial (e.g. IrfanView command line).

Comment: Is that from an image control? Was the data in the field attached as an OLE object or inserted from a JPG image?

Comment: it was inserted from an image copied from an internet page.

Comment: however I have gone down a different route now and used the Save Clipboard images to local file  function from this page      https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#save-clipboard-images-to-local-file and link the image via linked image control.   thanks for the help though